# AzureServiceTokenProvider().GettokenAsync() getting a token for for account that is no longer signed in

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I have the following logic

```
_sqlAccessToken = (new AzureServiceTokenProvider().GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/").Result;
```

which returns a token.  But when looking at the details of the token, it is for an account that is not signed into visual studio.  This account was signed in at one point, but now the account has changed.  How do I tell Visual Studio to use the new account.  I have tried evertying from sign out/sign back in, restart visual studio and restart pc.

Comment: Have you also checked you are not signed into the account with AZ CLI?

Comment: If you use visual studio to develop your application, you can try to use the account to login VS and choose the account to get access token. The steps is that ```Tools -> Options -> Azure Service Authentication -> Account Selection```.

Answer (score 0):

I met simliar issue before when you have different versions of VS on same computer. It was resolved by logining same account for all VS.